# "Property _ does not exist on _ type" D3.js typescript errors in Ionic 2 project

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript, ionic-framework, typescript-typings

I am trying to add a simple D3.js bar chart to a Ionic 2 project.

I imported d3 and installed the type definitions as follows:

```
npm install d3
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev --save-exact
```

I added the following in the TS file for the page:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
```

When running `ionic serve` it finds the definition file with no problem. When I try a simple chart example such as the following, it also works with no problem:

```
var sampleSVG = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);    

sampleSVG.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});
```

**However, when I try the following bar chart example (found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)), it doesn't work:**

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });
});
```

**I get a list of undefined typescript errors (even though the definition file for D3 v4 was successfully imported):**

```
[11:54:14]  typescript: src/pages/page1/page1.ts, line: 35 
            Property 'frequency' does not exist on type 'DSVRowString'. 

      L34:  d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
      L35:    d.frequency = +d.frequency;
      L36:    return d;

[11:54:14]  typescript: src/pages/page1/page1.ts, line: 35 
            Property 'frequency' does not exist on type 'DSVRowString'. 

      L34:  d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
      L35:    d.frequency = +d.frequency;
      L36:    return d;
[11:54:14]  typescript: src/pages/page1/page1.ts, line: 40 

            Property 'letter' does not exist on type 'DSVRowString'. 

      L40:    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
      L41:    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

[11:54:14]  typescript: src/pages/page1/page1.ts, line: 41 
            The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type 
            arguments explicitly. Type argument candidate 'DSVRowString' is not a valid type argument because it is not 
            a supertype of candidate 'string'. 

      L40:    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
      L41:    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
[11:54:14]  typescript: src/pages/page1/page1.ts, line: 59 

            Argument of type 'DSVParsedArray<DSVRowString>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: BaseType, 
            datum: {}, index: number, groups: ArrayLike<BaseType> | BaseType[]) => {}[]'. Type 
            'DSVParsedArray<DSVRowString>' provides no match for the signature '(this: BaseType, datum: {}, index: 
            number, groups: ArrayLike<BaseType> | BaseType[]): {}[]' 

      L58:  g.selectAll(".bar")
      L59:    .data(data)
      L60:    .enter().append("rect")

[11:54:14]  transpile failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround I just used `declare var d3: any;` in the model file (`src/pages/page1/page1.ts` in this case). To use this method I had to manually insert `<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>` in `src/index.html` instead of using import via Node.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you, that's what I was looking for for hours!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you haven't told typescript the *types* of your arguments in your callback.  How you do that is often tricky, so what I find useful is to look at the unit tests for the type-ings files.  For this case see [here](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/blob/master/tests/d3-dsv/d3-dsv-test.ts#L60).  Untested but it'll end up looking something like this:

```
interface ChartData {
  frequency: string;
  letter: number;      
}

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  let rr: d3Dsv.DSVRowString = d;
  let pr: ChartData;

  pr = {
    frequency: +rr['frequency'],
    letter: rr['letter']
  };

  return pr;
}, function(error, data:Array<ChartData>) {

  ...

}
```

Comment: This would have required a fair bit of work with the d3 related libraries I wanted to import so I just used the solution in my answer. You lose some of the safety but is handy when you need it running quickly.